# R : fill a column depending on a value and a vector

Tags: r

I have a data frame `users` with a column `id` and `country`

```
id                  country
1                   France
2                   United States
3                   France
```

I want to add a new column `salary` which depends on the average `salary` for a given `country`.

My first thought was to create a config vector with `(country, salary)` like this :

```
salary_country <- c(
   "France"=45000,
   "United States"=50000,
   ...)
```

And then to create the column like this (using `dplyr`) :

```
tbl_df(users) %>% 
  mutate(salary = ifelse(country %in% names(salary_country), 
                         salary_country[country], 
                         0))
```

It runs like a charm. If the country does not exist in my `salary_country` vector, the `salary` is equal to 0 else it's equal to the given `salary`.

But, it is quite slow on a very large data frame and quite verbose.

Is there a better way to accomplish that ?

Comment: Make `salary_country` a `data.frame`/`data.table` and `merge()` them with with `all = TRUE`, this will give you a `NA` where there is no average salary, which is IMO better than imputing `0`s. Edit: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: no need for explicit 'merge' if OP uses `data.table` ... the `data.table` merge syntax coupled with the 'on' attribute is enough. See the vignette in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match`:

```
salary_country[match(users$country, names(salary_country))]
```

Or go for `data.table`:

```
dt = data.table(salary=salary_country, country=names(salary_country))

dt[setDT(users), on='country']

#   salary       country id
#1:  45000        France  1
#2:  50000 United States  2
#3:  45000        France  3
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, merge is a good idea. I finally used left_join from dplyr package but this is the same idea of your answer.